# Mapbox Popup Marker Not Working on Mobile (Mapbox GL JS)

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating a map using Mapbox GL JS with popup markers. The popups work on Google Chrome Desktop and Mobile Landscape mode but not on Mobile Portrait Mode (IOS).

How can I solve this?

Here is a link to the page: https://bjj-blog.webflow.io/locations/birmingham-al

I've tried the following:

Added a data-tap-disabled ="true" custom attribute to the parent div